# Setting a active link css at first and dynamically change it

Tags: jquery, css, onclick, background-color

I have a menu with list items which have different background colours if someone clicks on it. I used this code to achieve that:

```
$(function() {
   var links = $('a.link').click(function() {
       links.removeClass('active');
       $(this).addClass('active');
   });
});
```

That worked fine. The CSS works fine too, so the colors change, but I have one issue and that is that I can't set a standard list item to have a background color BEFORE someone clicks on it. So I want to have a red background on a list item, before someone clicks on it. If someone clicks on a different list item, this red background color has to switch from the standard to the clicked one.

How can I achieve this?

This is the menu:

```
<nav id="navigation">
<ul id="quick-index-nav" class="slim">
<li>
<a class="link" href="#">First one</a>
</li>
<li>
<a class="link" target="main" href="#">Second one</a>
</li>
<li>
<a class="link" href="#">Third one</a>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added another removeClass in the script and gave a background-color on the list-item that I wanted to be highlighted before it was clicked. That worked like a charm.

```
$(function() {
    $('a.link').click(function() {
       $('.link').removeClass('active');
       $('.a-class-name').removeClass('a-class-name');
       $(this).addClass('active');
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you putting it in a var? And if you want a to select a class you need to put it in a jquery selector `$('.link')`

```
$(function() {
    $('a.link').click(function() {
       $('.link').removeClass('active');
       $(this).addClass('active');
   });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I will change it, but that is no answer to my question. I want to have a list item that has a background color before it is clicked in any way... And then, if someone clicks on to another list item, that color has to be removed and be on the list item that is clicked.

Comment: this is everything you need... rest is css. If you still don't understand, leave another comment

Comment: What do I not understand than? It was already working mate, that ain't the problem! But I want a color BEFORE somebody clicks! The code above does not provide that.

Comment: just give it background color with css and when it has the class active give it an other color.

Comment: Nope, I solved it my own way. Thanks though, you helped me a lot!